# How to trace a recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

I saw this code online but what I am asking is how did the program come up with an answer of  `12` ?

I did a tracing of the program, and I only come up with an answer of  `6` .

Why is the answer `12` ?

The inputs are `a=6` and `b=6`.

This is the code:

```
public static int addxy(int a, int b)
{
    if (a==0)
        return b;
    else if (b==0)
        return a;
    else
        return 1 + addxy(a, b-1);
}
```

Comment: Then you did your tracing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

- addxy(6,6)
- 1+addxy(6,5)
- 1+1+addxy(6,4)
- 1+1+1+addxy(6,3)
- 1+1+1+1addxy(6,2)
- 1+1+1+1+1+addxy(6,1)
- 1+1+1+1+1+1+addxy(6,0) = 12

Comment: What was the wrong in above solution.Please tell me and Why giving -1 mark?

Comment: @RavenMaddison I am sorry. But i would like know who is giving me vote down without giving any reason. Anyways its fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try walking over it step by step:

```
addxy(6, 6) returns 1 + addxy(6, 5)
addxy(6, 5) returns 1 + addxy(6, 4)
addxy(6, 4) returns 1 + addxy(6, 3)
addxy(6, 3) returns 1 + addxy(6, 2)
addxy(6, 2) returns 1 + addxy(6, 1)
addxy(6, 1) returns 1 + addxy(6, 0)
addxy(6, 0) returns 6
So, addxy(6, 1) returns 1 + 6 = 7
So, addxy(6, 2) returns 1 + 7 = 8
So, addxy(6, 3) returns 1 + 8 = 9
So, addxy(6, 4) returns 1 + 9 = 10
So, addxy(6, 5) returns 1 + 10 = 11
So, addxy(6, 6) returns 1 + 11 = 12
```

Comment: i still dont understand!! it returns 1 and the calling of the method... which is also 1.. and why does it have addxy(6, 1) it must be addxy(6, 5) so 6+5 =11.... i still dont understand... please help... im so stupid..

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 return 1 + addxy(a, b-1);
```

returns `1` plus the result of calling the method recursively while removing `1` from `b`. This basically means that it adds `b`.

When `b` is `0`, you return `a`.

```
else if (b==0)
    return a;
```

(You also return `b`, when `a` is `0`.

Without even tracing anything, you can tell that (with non-negative values for `a` and `b`) the method simply adds `a` and `b` and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `return` statement

```
return 1 + addxy(a, b-1);
```

You have a function call in the `return` statement to the same function. This is called a `recursive function`. So as long as b is not `0`, it keeps on calling it again n again but by adding `1` and subtracting `b` by `1`. This goes on till `b` becomes `0`. Which is 6 times. And thats why you get `1*6 + a = 6`

Equivalent execution would be

```
return 1 + addxy(6, 5);
return 1 + 1 + addxy(6, 4);
return 1 + 1 + 1 + addxy(6, 3);
return 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + addxy(6, 2);
return 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + addxy(6, 1);
return 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + addxy(6, 0);
return 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 6; // Value of a = 6
return 12;
```

Comment: no..the answer is 12 see it adds all values. value of a remains 6.

Comment: it returns 1 plus the name of the method.... using a = 6 and b=5 now.... then it falls again in the same statement to add 1 and b=4... and uses the same statement...  i still dont get it... im soooo stupid

Comment: in the return statement, the function is called again. read recursive functions. probably you'll get a better picture

Comment: i already read about the recursive functions!!! its too hard to understand... i can understand loops much better...but i have to know this...!!! :(

Comment: I dont where to explain you because comments is not a place to do that. But anyway think about it, the function is called every time the third return statement is executed. come to JAVA chat -> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java

Answer (score -1):

As @Mureinik answer is perfect but you didn't  understand it ,

So Lets start with a very basic example of Calculating Factorial via Recursion:

```
public int factorial(int num){
   if(num==0) //break condition of Recursion Since 0! is always 1
      return 1;
   return num*fact(num-1);
}
```

So here is the Tracing

```
factorial(4) return 4*factorial(3);
factorial(3) return 3*factorial(2);
factorial(2) return 2*factorial(1);
factorial(1) return 1*factorial(0);
factorial(0) returns 1;
```

, Now backtrace this answers and this below image is formed

[image: Recusrsion]

May Be now you are able to understand it