# How to trace these following codes? using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion

Value of a is 6. Answer is 12. How is it done?

```
    if (a==0)
        return 1;

    return (a*a)/addxy(a-1)
```

And this, value of a is 20. How come 11 is produced? It must be a negative answer since it becomes like 20-19-18-17-...and so on

```
    if (a==0)
        return 1;

    return a-addxy(a-1);
```

I dont understand how it is done.
PS: Ive been reading recursions in java like a thousand times. Still didnt get it. Someone kind, please help.

Comment: What does the function addxy do?

Comment: its the name of the method!!!!!!

Comment: Use a debugger, or some println

Comment: ive already use it....and all it does is decrement!!! i cant use a println after a return statement... we all know that!!

Comment: Post the entire function in the question, not just the body.

Comment: "i cant use a println after a return statement" in fact you can with a try{} finally{} but its not required here. see https://ideone.com/SWoKZ1 for an example

Comment: You've asked this question [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28524087/how-to-trace-a-recursion), and got 5 answers. These answers explain perfectly fine what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is your addxy method

```
int addxy(a){
  if (a==0)
        return 1;

    return (a*a)/addxy(a-1)
}
```

You are recursing and it turns out that this is what the calculation turns out to be.

(6*6)/((5*5)/((4*4)/((3*3)/((2*2)/((1*1)/(1))))))

Ok, now to show you why that is.  This is the stack that gets created when you call it:

```
a=6: (6*6)/(a=5)
a=5: (5*5)/(a=4)
a=4: (4*4)/(a=3)
a=3: (3*3)/(a=2)
a=2: (2*2)/(a=1)
a=1: (1*1)/(a=0)
a=0: 1
```

So thats what the stack looks like when it hits the base case, now pop off the stack until you're done.

```
a=6: (6*6)/(a=5)
a=5: (5*5)/(a=4)
a=4: (4*4)/(a=3)
a=3: (3*3)/(a=2)
a=2: (2*2)/(a=1)
a=1: (1*1)/1

a=6: (6*6)/(a=5)
a=5: (5*5)/(a=4)
a=4: (4*4)/(a=3)
a=3: (3*3)/(a=2)
a=2: (2*2)/1

a=6: (6*6)/(a=5)
a=5: (5*5)/(a=4)
a=4: (4*4)/(a=3)
a=3: (3*3)/4 // This is (9)/4, so integer division will happen

a=6: (6*6)/(a=5)
a=5: (5*5)/(a=4)
a=4: (4*4)/2 // Note the integer division that happened to get 2

a=6: (6*6)/(a=5)
a=5: (5*5)/8

a=6: (6*6)/3

a=6: 12
```

Comment: great!!! but how does the second code works?

Comment: it shouldn't be too complicated to adapt this answer to your second code right ? also smells like homework to me..

Comment: I'm not the back of a text book.  I showed you how to do one example.  If you understand it you should be able to do another of the same.  If you don't understand, then you should ask questions about the parts that don't make sense.

Comment: @RavenMaddison You may want to rethink your attitude. He's spending his own free time explaining you something (which has already been explained in your previous questions). If you really want to *learn* the 2nd part should be an easy exercise using a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

So this is your addxy method

```
int addxy(a){
  if (a==0)
        return 1;

    return (a*a)/addxy(a-1)
}
```

**For Input** : addxy(3);

**Output**

```
addxy(3) : will return (3*3)/addxy(2);
addxy(2) : will return (2*2)/addxy(1);
addxy(1) : will return (1*1)/addxy(0);
addxy(0) : will return (1);
```

Now backtrace :

```
(1*1)/1=1 <-------Since  addxy(0) is 1 
(2*2)/1=4 <------- Since return (1*1)/addxy(0); is 1
(3*3)/4=2 <--------- Since Integer Division so no decimal .
```

Final Result : **2**